# jQuery change inline style of multiple div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bellow html code and want to change

inline style

> display:block

to

> display:none

Where class is **ln-b** to **ln-z**

```
<div class="filter-div ln-b" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-c" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-d" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-e" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-f" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-g" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-h" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-i" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-j" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-k" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-l" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-m" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-n" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-o" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-p" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-q" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-r" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-s" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-t" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-u" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-v" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-w" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-x" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-y" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="filter-div ln-z" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest (assuming they appear in that order and are siblings), and *also* that there's a `.filter-div.ln-a` element that you don't want to hide:

```
$('.filter-div.ln-b').nextUntil($('.ln-z').next()).addBack().css('display','none');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tPV2c/).

References:

- [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).

Comment: Hey thanks for help but it is not working. class is generating ln-b to ln-z so no worries.

Comment: What does 'it is not working' *mean*? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addBack'

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi i have added jquery-1.9.1.js and now working but filter-div ln-z is still displaying display:block :(

Comment: Hey i just changed .ln-z to .ln-Z and it is working :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[class*="ln-"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".filter-div").css("display","none");
```

or

```
$('.filter-div').each(function() {
   $(this).css("display","none"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(".filter-div").attr('style', 'display:none');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RKdCd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div[class*="ln-"]').css('display','none');
```